# CSS Mega menu when hovering from a link to the next reverts to first selected link

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a mega menu using a guide I've found by Valeriu Timbuc here: https://designmodo.com/create-css3-mega-menu/

I've found out while playing around with it that when a menu item is selected to show the menu div (menu 1), then when you select another menu (menu 2) to show it's menu div, if you move your mouse below the selected menu div (menu 2 - as you would when you're trying to select an item from the newly selected div), the selected menu jumps back to your first selected menu item (menu 1).

This only happens for menu items going right to left - it does not happen for items going from left to right. *on the web demo it looks like it happens going both ways, on my personal test it only occurs going right to left*

To reproduce the behaviour, perform the following on the demo page here: https://designmodo.com/demo/css3megamenu/

1. hover on the "Earnings" menu item
2. hover on any menu items to it's left - say "Top Rated" or "What's New", (for this example, we will use the "What's New" link as this has items in the drop down menu)
3. as soon as the "What's New" items are displayed, move your mouse down to select an item from the "What's New" drop down menu
4. the screen jumps back to the "Earnings" menu.

Doing the same thing but in the opposite direction from left to right, that is, having the "What's New" menu item selected first, then hovering on the "Earnings" menu item will show the correct behaviour where moving the mouse will not jump back to the previously selected menu item.

To view what is happening in action, please have a look at the video here: https://imgur.com/a/3Jg4w0b

This mega menu is perfect for what I need to do apart from this medium issue. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: That only happens when you move too fast. If you wait until the animation has ended, it's OK. This is probably a bug in the original designer's code, which you should alert them to.

Comment: yeah unfortunately it happens even if you wait for the animation to "end". What I mean by this is, you wait for the screen to show up, then move down but it'll again revert to the previous screen. Can replicate it most of the time but don't really want to be in the state where you need to wait for it to load.

Answer (score 0):

After going through multiple mega menu solutions, I've figured out what seems to be causing this issue.

When defining menu items in the menu dropdown section, the CSS for the display should be set to "None" (instead of "Block" shown in the demo) to prevent the div from being accessible at all.

Even though the div seems hidden as the visibility and overflow is set to "Hidden", it looks like the div area still exists which is why hovering below the menu item still acts as if the previous drop down menu item has been selected as that drop down still has a div showing on screen.

On the hover CSS, the display should be set to "Block" which will only draw the element while you hover on the link.